# Proving Itô's Isometry

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Im currently trying to understand stochastic integration.

Reading through some lecture notes I encountered the following proof of Itô's Isometry for simple functions. Here $M_s$ is a $L^2$ integrable martingale starting at 0 and
$$ H_t = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty K_n \mathbb{1}_{(t_{n},t_{n+1}]} $$
is a simple predictable process.

Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_0^\infty H_s dM_s \right)^2 \right] &\overset{1}{=}  \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 (M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n})^2 \right] \\
&\overset{2}{=}\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[(M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n})^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right] \\
&\overset{3}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_{n+1}}^2-M_{t_n}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right] \\
&\overset{4}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[[M]_{t_{n+1}}-[M]_{t_n} | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right] \\
&\overset{5}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2([M]_{t_{n+1}}-[M]_{t_n}) \right] \overset{6}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^\infty H_s^2 d[M]_s \right]
\end{align}

I have trouble udnerstanding some parts of those equations. So lets go through each of them:

1. This is just the definition of the stochastic integral for simple functions.
2. This is the tower property for the conditional expectation.
3. I dont understand what is happending here.
   My calculations based on the comment by Bart:
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[(M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n})^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_{n+1}}^2-2M_{t_n}M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right]   \\
   &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \left( \mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_{n+1}}^2-M_{t_n}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] -2\mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_n}M_{t_{n+1}}| \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right]  \right) \right]   \\
   &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \left( \mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_{n+1}}^2-M_{t_n}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] -2M_{t_n}^2  \right) \right]   \\
   &\overset{3}{=} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n =0}^\infty K_n^2 \mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_{n+1}}^2-M_{t_n}^2 | \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] \right] \\
   \end{align}
   Here I still don't understand how to derive the last line.
4. I dont understand what is happending here. It is normally argued that $M_t^2-[M]_t$ is a martingale but i dont understand what this has to do with the proof.
5. Is this the tower property? I lack intuition why this is true.
6. $[M]_s$ is nondecreasing hence this integral is understood for example in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense.

Can you please help me understand this proof?

Comment: Wrt equation 3: write out the square of the difference between the brackets, then use the conditional expectation wrt Ftn and the martingale property.

Comment: Thank you. Why should $\mathbb{E}\left[M_{t_n}M_{t_{n+1}}| \mathcal{F}_{t_n}\right] $ be equal to zero?

Comment: It shouldn't. But using said properties one can show it equals $M_{t_n}^2$, which should then help you get the desired result.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? I'm just too stupid to see how this would help.

Comment: As user6247850 pointed out there is a slight mistake with one minus sign too much in the expansion of $(M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n})^2$. The rest you already have to obtain equality 3. But you had probably already come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3:

There's a slight mistake when you expand out $(M_{t_{n+1}}-M_{t_n})^2$.  It should be $M_{t_{n+1}}^2 - 2 M_{t_n} M_{t_{n+1}} {+} M_{t_n}^2$.  The rest of what you have is good, but now you'll end up with $M_{t_n}^2 - 2 M_{t_n}^2 = -M_{t_n}^2$ in the last line.

For 4:

Let $N_t := M_t^2 - [M]_t$, which is a martingale as you mentioned.  Given $t > s$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M_{t}^2 - M_{s}^2|\mathcal F_s] &= \mathbb{E}[M_t^2-[M]_t - (M_s^2 - [M]_s) + [M]_t - [M]_s | \mathcal F_s] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[N_t - N_s+ [M]_t - [M]_s | \mathcal F_s] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[[M]_t - [M]_s | \mathcal F_s].
\end{align*}
Applying this with $t = t_{n+1}$ and $s = t_n$ gives the result.

For 5:

Yes, this is the tower property.  We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum K_n^2 \mathbb{E}[[M]_{t_{n+1}} - [M]_{t_n} | \mathcal F_{t_n}] \right] &=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum \mathbb{E}[K_n^2([M]_{t_{n+1}} - [M]_{t_n} )| \mathcal F_{t_n}] \right] \\
&= \sum \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[K_n^2([M]_{t_{n+1}} - [M]_{t_n} )| \mathcal F_{t_n}]]\\
&= \sum \mathbb{E}[K_n^2([M]_{t_{n+1}} - [M]_{t_n} )] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum K_n^2([M]_{t_{n+1}} - [M]_{t_n} )\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. This helped me a lot.

Comment: @Rooibos Sorry, I didn't see that you hadn't fully resolved line 3.  I added an explanation of that.